# Не могу использовать прокси

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, python-3.6, telebot

```
import telebot
#from telebot import apihelper

tn = ""
bot = telebot.TeleBot(tn)

telebot.apihelper.proxy={'https':'socks5://teleForever_user:frg45yFgg4L@45.77.59.101:10080'}
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
 def hendler_text(massage):
    print("dd")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"ky")


if __name__== "__main__":
   bot.polling(none_stop=True)</b>
```

Ошибка:

> (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred,
>   args=('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server
>   returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response
>   body:\n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict:
>   terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot
>   instance is running"}\']',) Traceback (most recent call last):

В чём проблема?

Comment: Не могу подключиться к api.telegram.irg

Comment: Ошибку перевести не пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал, все разное пишут